# Using Qt.Include() in script passed into QScriptEngine.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I would like to use QScriptEngine in a program to run a set of custom script files associated with our project.  Our scripts will need to include other scripts and I was looking into how to do this with using Qt.Include().  I set up an example program below to see if this was possible but I receive an error saying it cannot find the variable Qt.

Aside from creating my own preprocessor before sending the contents to `engine.evaluate()`, is there any way to do this?

My main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QtScript>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(helloscript);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QScriptEngine engine;

    QString fileName(":/hello.js");
    QFile scriptFile(fileName);
    scriptFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream stream(&scriptFile);
    QString contents = stream.readAll();
    scriptFile.close();

    QScriptValue result = engine.evaluate(contents, fileName);

    if (result.isError()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Hello Script",
                          QString::fromLatin1("%0:%1: %2")
                          .arg(fileName)
                          .arg(result.property("lineNumber").toInt32())
                          .arg(result.toString()));
        return -1;
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

My hello.js:

```
Qt.include("other.js");  // Can't find variable Qt
func();
```

My other.js:

```
function func() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

Error:

```
:/hello.js:1: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Qt
```

Comment: What is `Qt.Include()`? It's not a part of `QScriptEngine` API.

Comment: It's possible to call Qt.include() when inside of QML.  An example of it is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#including-a-javascript-resource-from-another-javascript-resource

Comment: For `QtScript` you have to implement your own `include()` using `QScriptEngine::newFunction()`.